# Not able to view the buttons at the bottom of the screen after view pager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

So I want to show two buttons below ViewPager element in my layout. I am not able to see either in the simulator, or in the layout inspector. This is my layout xml set up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
        android:text="@string/first_crime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/first_button"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
    <Button
        android:text="@string/last_crime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/last_button"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/crime_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is how it looks in the design tool.

[image: View Pager layout Using FrameLayout]

This is the second approach.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/crime_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/first_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/first_crime"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/last_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/last_crime"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is how it looks in design mode.

[image: View Pager layout using Constraint layout]

I want to see the buttons at the bottom of the screen in my simulator. here is what I see.

[image: View Pager In Simulator]

Here is the screenshot from the layout inspector.
[image: Layout Inspector]

**UPDATE** I have updated the layout using ConstraintLayout, but I still don't see the buttons in the simulator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/first_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/first_crime"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/last_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/last_crime"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/crime_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the layout shown inside the ViewPager element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:text="@string/crime_title_label"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/crime_title_hint"
        android:id="@+id/crime_title_text"
        android:inputType="none"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:text="@string/crime_details_label"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:padding="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/crime_date_button"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_solved_label"
        android:id="@+id/crime_solved"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am learning Android programming, so if I have excluded any other information, then I would be happy to provide the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current parent layout is [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout) . as the doc says:

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child
>   on top. The size of the FrameLayout is the size of its largest child
>   (plus padding), visible or not (if the FrameLayout's parent permits).

so buttons are overlapped by viewpager.
you could use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout). Which is widely used in android development.

Here is a example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn1" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I would appreciate it if you can show me a sample layout example.

Comment: I still don't see the buttons. I have included the layout of fragment within the view pager.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with you layout. Your ViewPager widget is not aligned above your buttons. This will lead to your view overlapping your buttons.

So, to fix it. Instead of a FrameLayout has a parent use a ConstraintLayout or a RelativeLayout.

Then align the ViewPager at the top of the parent and **above your buttons container.**

Comment: I would appreciate if you could show me a sample example.